# Convert String 'shorter' to 'short' using Python nltk stem package

Tags: python, nltk, stemming

I am trying to extract the stem of the words `taller` and `shorter` from  a string in python.

I did the following:

```
>>> from nltk.stem.porter import *
>>> print(stemmer.stem('shorter'))
shorter
>>> print(stemmer.stem('taller'))
taller
```

And for some reason, I don't get the words `tall` and `short`. Anyone knows how to possibly fix this, or possibly guide to an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few stemmers.  Here's one:

```
>>> from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
>>> stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
>>> stemmer.stem('shorter')
'short'
```

Comment: @wim Thanks for the insight. But notice taller --> tal .

Comment: Hmm .. sorry, not really my area - maybe you have to train them?

Comment: @wim I'm not sure how would that work. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from nltk import stem
>>> s = 'short'; t = 'tall'
>>> porter = stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
>>> lancaster = stem.lancaster.LancasterStemmer()
>>> snowball = stem.snowball.EnglishStemmer()
>>> porter.stem(s)
u'short'
>>> porter.stem(t)
u'tall'
>>> lancaster.stem(s)
'short'
>>> lancaster.stem(t)
'tal'
>>> snowball.stem(s)
u'short'
>>> snowball.stem(t)
u'tall'
```